# Erro ao usar método da MainActivity em um fragment

Tags: android, android-fragment, método

Estou tentando utilizar um metodo que retorna uma lista, quando utilizo esse mesmo metodo dentro da mainactivity aonde ele foi criado tudo funciona bem, porem ao tentar acessa-lo em um fragmente da erro NullPointerException.

log:

```
06-24 14:29:11.829 32645-32645/? D/Logzin: chamou api
06-24 14:29:11.839 32645-32645/? D/Logzin: colocou a playlist na mplaylist
06-24 14:29:11.839 32645-32645/? D/Logzin: catch java.lang.NullPointerException

                                           [ 06-24 14:29:11.859 32645:32645 D/         ]
                                           HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb98ce920, tid 32645


                                           [ 06-24 14:29:11.869 32645:32645 W/         ]
                                           Unrecognized GLES max version string in extensions: ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1
```

Método na Main:

```
public  List<PlaylistItem> getlistavideos(){

    try {
        mplaylistItems = playlistItems;
        Log.d(TAG,"colocou a playlist na mplaylist");

    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"Catch Main " + e);
    }


    return mplaylistItems;
}
```

Como estou tentando chama-lo no fragment:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlistavideos,container,false);
    /*mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    mList.add(mList.size(),"Um");
    mList.add(mList.size(),"Dois");
    */

    try {
        int tamanho= ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getlistavideos().size();
        Log.d(TAG,"Tamanho da Lista "+ tamanho);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d(TAG,"catch "+e);
    }


    return v;
}
```

Comment: Como já foi respondido em 2 outras perguntas sobre esta mesma lista que você fez. Você tem que primeiro fazer a chamada da consulta de lista e assim que ela for preenchida você cria o fragment, ou você tem que fazer o preenchimento da lista dentro da fragment

Answer (score 1):

tente executar o seu código dentro do evento onActivityCreated

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        try {
    int tamanho= ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getlistavideos().size();
    Log.d(TAG,"Tamanho da Lista "+ tamanho);
}catch (Exception e){
    Log.d(TAG,"catch "+e);
}
}
```

Comment: funcionou, porem quando o app inicia q ele abre o fragment a primeira vez ele da erro ( porem o app continua a funcionar ), só funciona quando clico no botão que faz o fragmente abrir novamente pela segunda vez, dai ele me retorna o tamanho da lista. veja:

Comment: 06-24 15:20:53.939 15778-15778/? D/Logzin: chamou api
06-24 15:20:53.939 15778-15778/? D/Logzin: colocou a playlist na mplaylist
06-24 15:20:53.939 15778-15778/? D/Logzin: catch java.lang.NullPointerException
06-24 15:20:59.349 15778-15778/br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal D/Logzin: chamou api
06-24 15:20:59.349 15778-15778/br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal D/Logzin: colocou a playlist na mplaylist
06-24 15:20:59.349 15778-15778/br.com.igoroliv.youtubecanal D/Logzin: Tamanho da Lista 5